# Dspace Enron Search Facility

Tags: xml, csv, indexing, metadata, dspace

I have been  working on a project on Dspace
I have been using Enron Mail Corpus (downloaded from CMU source).

My problem is :

1. I want to take entire collection of 600k emails and then generate a repository which enables search on them

Manually Feeding metadata of Each Mail is not a viable option as they are in millions!
Can the import facility in Dspace Be of any help? or is there a file to be edited?

I need something feasible and fast: *What should I do to feed the system with so many mails?*

1. Second question: Can the attached file within any collection be indexed? I mean can I search for the content of the file search facility?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit or import a large amount of data, you can use batch metadata editing. Its perfect for import metadata values, but files must be added manually later.
More information at https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC3x/Batch+Metadata+Editing#BatchMetadataEditing-TheCSVFiles

About the second question, there is a process that index supported files called "Filter-media". It support Adobe PDF, HTML, Text, Microsoft Word and Microsoft Powerpoint. And you can write a java class to index other formats to your needs.
Its executed doing /bin/dspace filter-media, and should be added as a cron.